Randomness in torch.utils.data.random_split vs. numpy based splitting
I'm implementing a convolutional neural network in PyTorch using the PyTorch Lightning infrastructure.
My collaborators asked me to evaluate the across dataset performance using kfold cross validation (yes, I am aware of data leakage and overfitting).
My problem is that numpy based random splitting yields significantly worse performances than torch.utils.data.random_split. My test performance using the train/val/test approach is around AUC 0.95, using a 8:1:1 split.

5 fold CV using manual numpy splitting yeilds an AUC of 0.88
5 fold CV using automatic pytorch random_split yields an AUC of 0.95

The sample size used to calculate the AUC is around 10,000 so the AUC difference between the two approaches is significant.
My question is why the pytorch random_split function returns better results? In my numpy implementation, the probability of belonging to given folds are independent between observations. Is that the case for the random_split function or does it e.g., use random intervals of samples?
Kfold Experiments
When I subset my dataset using numpy i get performances around AUC=0.88. Here is my code:
fold    = 1
indices = np.arange(X.shape[0])
sampler = np.random.permutation(indices) % 5 # 5 fold CV
X_train, X_test = X[(sampler!=fold)], X[(sampler==fold)]
y_train, y_test = y[(sampler!=fold], y[(sampler==fold)]

dataset = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(X_train), torch.Tensor(y_train))
train_dataset, val_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [0.9, 0.1])
test_dataset  = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(X_test), torch.Tensor(y_test))

When I subset my dataset using random_split in pytorch i get performances around AUC=0.95. Here is my code:
fold = 1
dataset       = TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(X), torch.Tensor(y))
five_folds    = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [1/5]*5) # 5 fold CV
test_dataset  = five_folds[fold]
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset(
    [five_folds[i] for i in range(5) if i != fold]
)
train_dataset, val_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(train_dataset, [0.9, 0.1])


Do you consistently see the same results with different random splits?

Yes. The performances are fairly stable when going from 5 fold to 20 fold CV in numpy. And tried different random number generators in torch random_split which also yield similar performances.

In your implementations above, it looks like for your numpy-dervied training dataset just  contains 1/5 of the total data, whereas for you PyTorch-derived dataset your training ConcatDataset contains all the data.

Hmm thanks, but I think/hope it contains 4/5 of the data (only checked test size). If sampler = [1, 4, 2, 1, 0 ...] then (sampler != 1) = [False, True, True, False, True ...]. All True indices go to the training data and all false go to the test data. I use this setup to run it in parallel across multiple nodes on a cluster.

Sorry, I misread you code!
